# Problems with Sigma BC 7.16 setup

Tags: computer

I bought a Sigma BC 7.16 bike computer. I can not figure out how to set the wheel size and change from km/hr to mph. There is one button and it just scrolls through different settings with no way to change them.

Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps the manual might be off some use?  Along with the video's Sigma have published would think that's a decent start point https://more.sigmasport.com/en/service/faq/fahrrad-computer/wired/wired/bc716?step=details

Comment: Did it come with a large paper sheet ?   These units generally have another button on the back that needs to be pressed with a pen/etc to activate programming functions

Comment: @Criggie You are right, there was a button on the back.

Comment: There is a good video here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZO8E_fjMsE

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Hursey for a link to the manual. The manual for the BC 7.16 is easy to find on the internet. e.g. [Here](https://more.sigmasport.com/en/service/faq/fahrrad-computer/wired/wired/bc716?step=details) or [enter link description here](https://more.sigmasport.com/en/service/faq/fahrrad-computer/wired/wired/bc716?step=details)

As suggested by @Criggie, the BC7.16 is like many of the cycle computers and has a button on the back for setting it up. In this case, it requires a press and hold for 5 seconds to get into setup mode.